# java HashCode cannot retrieve entries

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a bug that I am not able to solve. My HashMap has some entries, but I am unable to retrieve them through the key.
The keys do have hashCode and equals overridden, but as far as I know, they're working fine. They were implementing using eclipse's generator
The following code proves the problem. The HashMap refuses to admit it contains a key that itself provided. Other methods like get do not work either.

```
HashMap<SimpleTurn, Turn> turns = node.turns;
System.out.println("verifying HashMap turns"); 
System.out.println(" class : "+turns.getClass().getName()+" "+turns.getClass().getCanonicalName());
for(SimpleTurn sp : turns.keySet()){
    System.out.println("Am I equal to myself : "+sp.equals(sp));
    System.out.println("Do I belong to my collection : "+turns.containsKey(sp));
}
```

Please note that I explicitly try to check my implementation of equals and it seems to work fine. 
The output from the above code is:

```
verifying HashMap turns
class : java.util.HashMap java.util.HashMap
Am I equal to myself : true
Do I belong to my collection : false
Am I equal to myself : true
Do I belong to my collection : false
Am I equal to myself : true
Do I belong to my collection : false
```

This behaviour is consistent throughout the code and What could be possible causing this behaviour? Any hints to what I should be looking for?
Thank you very much

Comment: Have the keys been modified after you entered them in the hashmap?

Comment: Your hashcodes are probably changing.

Comment: Show us your hashCode and equals code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing can only happen if your `hashCode` returns something different than the value it used when first inserting the key. For example

```
public class Main {     
    public int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   //Read user input into the array
        HashSet<Main> set = new HashSet<>();
        Main main = new Main();
        main.count = 3;

        set.add(main);
        main.count = 2; // changes what hashCode() returns 

        System.out.println(set.contains(main)); // prints false
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

A `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` in its underlying implementation.

The key is stored at a position defined by the original `hashCode()` value of `3`. We modify the object and try to check if the `Set` contains it. The `contains()` method will call the `hashCode()` method again, which returns `2`, and checks if there is an element defined (bucket) with that value. It doesn't find any and so returns `false`.

You must be modifying the object that is acting as the key after you add them to the `Map`.